# Feature Flag Capability

Tags: java, launchdarkly, feature-flags

I want to migrate me services to use Feature Flag Capabilities from: [LaunchDarkly](https://launchdarkly.com/) to [AWS AppConfig feature flags](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/using-aws-appconfig-feature-flags/)

Are they work the same?

What are the major differences?

Can I use Java Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is overlap between the two solutions. However, there are some key differences, which may or may not matter to you, depending on your use-case.

For example, AWS AppConfig has native integrations with other AWS services like Lambda; see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sq2HcRMLaLU. Pricing is different too (AWS AppConfig is pay-as-you-go). And per your question, AWS AppConfig does have AWS Java SDK support: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/appconfig/AmazonAppConfigClient.html

FYI - I work on AWS AppConfig.